# What causes system to halt

Tags: ssh, crash, log

I have a security camera server running on Ubuntu 20.04. When I leave I can login into the camera client and access the server via ssh. However occasionally and now more frequently the system client no longer sees the server and I can no longer ssh into it to reboot it. This being at a cottage I cannot unplug and plug back in until I get there. When I do that, it all comes back online.

So I am suspecting a possible overheat, or something else causing the system halt. I would like to know how to see what is causing the halt. If there is a way to determine the condition.

Comment: See shutdown log `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e`.

Comment: How to i go back to a specific date and time?

Comment: Click on my AskUbuntu id, and look at my AskUbuntu profile. There's a section on `journalctl`.